# Кодировка php и mysql

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

Использую бесплатный хостинг hut и возникла проблемы с БД. Делаю выборку из таблицы и  заместо русского текста выводятся вопросы. Кодировка php windows-1251, а в mysql cp1251_bin, но по-моему это одно и то же...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй сделать:

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251", $db);
```

Первым запросом к базе после подключения. И это не одно и тоже - cp1251_general_ci не чувствительна к регистру, в отличии от cp1251_bin.

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT title,meta_d,meta_k,text FROM settings WHERE page='index'",$db);//записываем в переменную
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);//вытаскиваем всё в массив

с mysql плохо знаком...так что не мог бы проделать тоже самое с этим кодом?

Comment: Ищешь где устанавливается подключение к базе: mysql_connect() и после этого вбиваешь mysql_query(), который я привел выше.

Comment: я понял что это надо писать в mysql_query(); но где именно надо прописать это исходя из моего кода?

Answer (score 1):

cp1251_bin
это меня смущает. Там есть  cp1251_general_ci
это первое. Далее, возможно, данные могли извратиться уже на этапе вставки. Проверьте прямо в базе - они там нормальные?
второе: SET NAMES cp1251 - как уже указали, обязательно при подключении к базе, если хотите работать именно с cp1251.
Ну и такое понятие, как "кодировка в PHP" - такого нет. обработка может быть..

Comment: я чего и добиваюсь...узнать как и где использовать SET NAMES cp1251

Comment: всё разобрался...спасибо помогло))

Comment: при подключении к базе.